# @Transactional in @Service ignored

Tags: spring-data, spring-transactions

If I put 'mode="aspectj"' into 'tx:annotation-driven' tag, then Spring-data handles transactions only in @Repository files, and not in @Service classes.

Here is my @Service to retrieve users:

```
@Service
public class RepositoryAuthService implements AuthService{

    @Resource
    AuthUserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public User findByCredentials(String userName, String password){
        User user = userRepository.getByCredentials(userName, password);
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().toString();
        ...
    }
```

Here is my spring-context:

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="my.jpatest.dao.auth" />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.jpatest.dao.auth">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan> 
<bean class="my.jpatest.dao.auth.RepositoryAuthService" id="authService" />
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(TransactionAspectSupport.java:111)
    at my.jpatest.dao.auth.RepositoryAuthService.findByCredentials(RepositoryAuthService.java:34)
```

I tried 'aspectj' with 'proxy-target-class="true"' but did not help. Without mode="aspectj" everything is fine: the connection remains after the repository-call as expected.

There is a detailed article about that, but this is quite long:
http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/spring-transactional-explained/

Any tips?

Regards:
    bence

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a little bit old, but perhaps it might work for someone later,

I think the reason is that you have:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.jpatest.dao.auth">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>
```

and there it says that it must only inspect classes annotated with Repository annotation, if you want also classes annotated with service just add one more include line like:

```
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
```

that should be it.